# Retrieving map values using nested variable in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy and pretty green to programming in general.  I'm working on a POC that uses Groovy to parse values from an input and prepare them to insert into a query downstream.  The issue is that, the input is structured differently, if there is 1 value or multiple values that need to be extracted.  I have found a way to generate the return string when receiving a single value, or receiving multiple values.  However I'm trying to create a solution that can handle both use cases.
To handle multiple instances of `records` this works:

```
def stringMap =[['Case_Plans__r':['queryLocator':null, 'done':'true', 'records':[['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'], ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000001qRdtEAE','Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'], ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCnEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c']],'size':3],'Id':'500c0000002AJclAAG', 'type':'Case']]
stringMap=stringMap.Case_Plans__r.records.Plan__c
String returnValue = stringMap[0].collect{"'$it'"}.join(',')
println ("prepared string is $returnValue")
```

This returns the expected result:

```
prepared string is 'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO','a0Ic0000001qRdtEAE','a0Ic0000002JWCnEAO'
```

If the source data has only one instance of `records` the structure changes to this and I cannot use the index of [0] or each character of the value will be split in the `returnValue`:

```
def stringMap=[['Case_Plans__r':['queryLocator':null, 'done':'true', 'records':['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'],'size':1],'Id':'500c0000002AJclAAG', 'type':'Case']]
stringMap=stringMap.Case_Plans__r.records.Plan__c
String returnValue = stringMap.collect{"'$it'"}.join(',')
println ("prepared string is $returnValue")
```

This returns the expected result,
prepared string is 'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO'

I've had trouble collecting the values using findAll or evaluating the `records` size of `Plan__c` to determine which assignment to utilize.  Is there a way to collect the values of `Plan__c` regardless of where it may be nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the resulting list when you get `Plan__c`:

```
stringMap=[
  ['Case_Plans__r':
    [
      'queryLocator':null, 
      'done':'true', 
      'records': ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'],
      'size':1
    ],
    'Id':'500c0000002AJclAAG', 
    'type':'Case'
  ]
]

assert stringMap.Case_Plans__r.records.Plan__c
    .flatten()
    .collect{"'$it'"}
    .join(',') == "'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO'"
```

For multiple records:

```
stringMap=[
  ['Case_Plans__r':
    [
      'queryLocator':null, 
      'done':'true', 
      'records':[
        ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'], 
        ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000001qRdtEAE','Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c'], 
        ['Plan__c':'a0Ic0000002JWCnEAO', 'Id':null, 'type':'Case_Plan__c']
      ],
      'size':3
    ],
    'Id':'500c0000002AJclAAG', 
    'type':'Case'
  ]
]

assert stringMap.Case_Plans__r.records.Plan__c
    .flatten()
    .collect{"'$it'"}
    .join(',') == "'a0Ic0000002JWCiEAO','a0Ic0000001qRdtEAE','a0Ic0000002JWCnEAO'"
```

Comment: Thanks Will!  This works perfectly.  I was experimenting with flatten, but wasn't utilizing it correctly.  I had ended up with cleaning up the string returned like this:
    stringMap=stringMap.Case_Plans__r.records.Plan__c.collectNested{"'$it'"}.join(",")
    def returnValue = stringMap.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")

Thanks for the example on how to properly use flatten!